# How to import Maven external jar (name without version) to local repo?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

I am migrating a simple Eclipse (ant based project) to Maven. I have created the pom.xml file with the generic dependencies, but now I need to add to the project the external jars (this are custom jars but we don't have the source code of most of them)

I have a list of jars (dependant among them) that I want to import to my local .m2 repository.
The naming convention of this is something like this

- foobar.jar
- foobarOne.jar (dependant of foobar.jar)
- etc

The problem is that when a local jar file is added, Maven rename them to this format `foobar-1.0.jar`, adding the version number and the dependencies between local jar files no longer work.

Is there a way of avoid this behaviour on file import or anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

I developed a simple Python script to add all dependencies to the local repo (this script must be executed before starting with the development)

```py
import os
import subprocess

def install_jars(directory):
    # Traverse the directory to find JAR files
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".jar"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                # Extract filename without extension
                filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
                # Install the JAR file into the local Maven repository
                install_command = f"mvn install:install-file -Dfile={file_path} -DgroupId=local -DartifactId={filename} -Dversion= -Dpackaging=jar"
                subprocess.run(install_command, shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify the directory containing your JAR files
    # TODO: Pending define correct path
    jar_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\\dependencies";
    install_jars(jar_directory)
```

And then I have added the references to the pom.xml.

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>local</groupId>
      <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why the names of the JARs matter. Regardless of the name, in the running Java applications, the classes are on the classpath and can be called. JARs don't call other JARs using their name.

Comment: Your Python code does not extract the version.

Comment: “ the dependencies between local jar” - what does this mean?